# How to avoid underfull \hbox warning when using wraptable

Tags: wrapfig

I have tried to include a wraptable in my paper, but one of the paragraphs above the table is unnecessarily "stretched" - something I guess is related to the warning "Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines.." that I also get?

Any idea how I can avoid this? I am compiling in pdfLaTeX.

Code for the text:

```
Even though Russia still utilises 'old media channels' (e.g. television, radio and 
newspapers) to reach both its domestic audience and audiences outside of its national 
borders, the reach is limited to Russian speaking minorities abroad. Thus, the Russian
state relies heavily on social media to reach non-Russian speaking audiences in the 
West (\citeauthor{ramsay2019weaponising}, \citeyear{ramsay2019weaponising}). 
\input{Images/Tables/SoMe platforms}Examining how Russia utilises the possibilities of
social media platforms is therefore an important area of research for disciplines such as 
political science, international studies, media and communication etc.
```

Code for the table:

```
\begin{wraptable}{r}{3.9cm}

\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\vspace{-3.3mm}
\footnotesize
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{\label{SoMe platforms}\\Most popular platforms}

{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.9}
\begin{tabular}{cc} \hline \hline 
Platform & Active users \\ \hline
Facebook & 2,853 \\
YouTube & 2,291 \\
WhatsApp & 1,386 \\ 
Instagram & 1,386 \\
WeChat & 1,242 \\ 
TikTok & 732 \\ 
Telegram & 550 \\ 
Sina Weibo & 530 \\ 
Snapchat & 514 \\ 
Pinterest & 478 \\ 
Reddit & 430 \\ 
Twitter & 397 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}}

\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft] \vspace{-0.2cm}
\item{Note: Counted in millions}.\vspace{-0.15cm}
\item{Source: \citeauthor{StatistaB} (\citeyear{StatistaB})}.\vspace{0.1cm}
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\vspace{-3.5mm}
\end{wraptable}
```

Code for preamble:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{article}

%%%% Packages
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc} % Selv tilføjet
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\babeltags{ru=russian, en=english}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, citestyle=apa, sorting=nyt ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Biblo.bib}
\usepackage{eso-pic} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper, hmargin={2.5cm, 3cm}, vmargin={3cm, 3cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\graphicspath{ {figures/} }
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[font=small,format=plain,labelfont=bf,textfont=normal,justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{float}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{etoolbox}\apptocmd\appendix{\pretocmd\section{\clearpage}{}{}}{}{}
\usepackage{subfiles} 

% Extra packages
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{bmpsize}
\usepackage{topcapt}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

% Commands
\setstretch{1.25}
\newcommand{\margmod}[1]{\marginnote{\setstretch{.5}\parbox[t]{\marginparwidth}{\raggedright\emph{#1}}}}

%%%% Front page % ændrer senere!
\def \ColourPDF {Images/Metaimages/Front page_Political Science.pdf}
\def \TitlePDF   {Images/Metaimages/Front page_Political Science.pdf}

\author{
  \LARGE{My full name} \\
  \vspace{0cm} \\
  {Academic Supervisor: Add name} \\
  \vspace{.5cm} \\
}

\title{
  \vspace{3mm}
  \Huge{Master's Thesis}\\
  \vspace{18mm}
  \LARGE{Enter title name}
  \vspace{90mm}
}

\date{March 2022}

%%%% Layout style
\linespread{1.5}
\fancyhead[L]{} 
\fancyhead[R]{\slshape \rightmark}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

%%%% Front page layout
\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\AddToShipoutPicture*{\put(0,602){\includegraphics*[viewport=0 600 700 1600]{\ColourPDF}}}
\AddToShipoutPicture*{\put(0,0){\includegraphics*{\TitlePDF}}}

\clearpage\maketitle 
\thispagestyle{empty}

\newpage

%%%% Meta info
%\begin{table}[!ht]
\begin{table}[!h]
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\vspace{5mm}
 \textbf{University} & & {University of Copenhagen} \\
 \vspace{5mm}
 \textbf{Name of Department} & & {Department of Political Science} \\
 \vspace{5mm}
 \textbf{Study Programme} & & {Master of Science (MSc) in Political Science} \\ 
 \vspace{5mm}
 \textbf{Author} & & {My full name} \\ 
 \vspace{5mm}
 \textbf{Student ID} & & {Add ID} \\
 \vspace{5mm}
 \textbf{Academic Supervisor} & & {Add name} \\
 \textbf{Title} & & {Title - line 1} \vspace{0.5mm}
\cr & & {Title - line 2} 
\\ \\
 \textbf{Date of Submission} & & {Add date} \\ 
\\
 \textbf{ECTS} & & {30} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\newpage

Start of paper..
```

Screnshot of the output:

[image: Screenshot]

**Addendum:**

Updated preamble:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{article}

%%%% Packages
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\babeltags{ru=russian, en=english}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, citestyle=apa, sorting=nyt ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Biblo.bib}
\usepackage{eso-pic} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper, hmargin={2.5cm, 3cm}, vmargin={3cm, 3cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\graphicspath{ {figures/} }
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[font=small,format=plain,labelfont=bf,textfont=normal,justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{float}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{etoolbox}\apptocmd\appendix{\pretocmd\section{\clearpage}{}{}}{}{}
\usepackage{subfiles} 

% Extra packages
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{bmpsize}
\usepackage{topcapt}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{microtype}   % <--- new
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{tabularray} % <--- new
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx, varwidth} % <--- new
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
```

Tabularray package:
[image]

Output when testing the compilation of proposed solution by Zarko:
[image]

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete, compilable document.

Comment: Sure! I have extended the code now. Would you still recommend your suggestions below after having seen my preamble?

Comment: I tried implementing your suggestions below, but it didn't work out very well for me - the output ended up even more messier. The \UseTblrLibrary package seemed to cause the issues.

Comment: Which version of `tabularray` you have installed? With 2021Q it should work as advertised ;-). See addendum to my answer,

Comment: Hm, how can I check the version? :) I get the error "Environment tallblr undefined". See addendum to my answer.

Comment: You probably mean: "...addendum to my  question."  Error tell you that you need to upgrade `tabularray` package (to version 2021Q), the best by help of some wizard (at MiKTeX by MiKTeX Console). Do you consider the suggestion in addendum to my answer? Please test it as it is.

Comment: Yes, I meant ".. to my question." I was not familiar with MikTex, but it's downloaded now, and it seems that I have updated the tabularray package correctly. When I test the code from your addendum (both in my paper and in a blank project), I still get the error "Environment tallblr undefined" :-/ It's the correct package I have installed, right? (see latest update in addendum).

Comment: Yes, it is correct. If you copy my main document from addendum in some of your folders and then  add the file `wraptable.txt`, the compilation of proposed solution should work.  Try before test delete `aux. ` file which you have in folders. BTW, do you load it as administrator and as user?

Comment: I deleted `aux.` files and compiled your proposed solution once again, but I keep getting the same error and messy output (see latest update in addendum). I'm not sure whether I load it as administrator and user - how can I check that? Appreciate your patience btw. I will probably move forward soon and return to the wraptable issue at a later point :-/

Comment: I'm very sorry, my crystal bal escape to skiing (since weather is excellent for this ...  )  , so cant see what you doing and what a mess you have in your computer. I only see, that in your preamble is missed  `\input{insbox}`. Added it to preamble and test again my proposed solution, it works like charm and gives result as I shown in my answer. How you install MiKTeX? As single user? Or multiuser?  One (desperate and hard) solution can be remove  (thoroughly, by use of Console) MiKTeX from your computer and then make fresh installation of it..

Comment: Hehe, all good! :) Yep, already included `\input{insbox}`. Made a fresh installation of MikTeX and tested your proposed solution (both your first one and the updated one in your appendum) in a blank Overleaf project. I think I installed it as multiuser (I chose the shared system-wide configuration). Still getting the same error (Environment tallblr undefined) and messy output though. If I a later point figure out what is causing my problem, I will let you know... :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**
In MWE are now considered relevant part of provided document preamble. Also `wraptable` is now inserted in the middle of paragraph.

- you should provide MWE (Minimal working Example), a small, but complete document example, which reproduce your problem (as example see my MWE below))
- With:

  - adding option for number of spanning text lines
  - make `wraptable` a bit wider, and
  - for table in `wraptable` use `tabularray` package with its libraries `booktabs` and `siunitx` (which call packages of the same names), and `varwidth` (specific to `tabularray`, needed for measuring of cells widths).

  Compilation of edited MWE produce:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, 
            hmargin={2.5cm, 3cm}, 
            vmargin={3cm, 3cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document

\usepackage{microtype}   % <--- new
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx, varwidth}
\usepackage[style=apa, 
            citestyle=apa, 
            sorting=nyt ]{biblatex}

\begin{document}
Even though Russia still utilises 'old media channels' (e.g. television, radio and newspapers) to reach both its domestic audience and audiences outside of its national borders, the reach is limited to Russian speaking minorities abroad. Thus, the Russian state relies heavily on social media to reach non-Russian speaking audiences in the West (\citeauthor{ramsay2019weaponising}, \citeyear{ramsay2019weaponising}). 
%
\input{wraptable.txt} % if it is in the same folder as document
%
Examining how Russia utilizes the possibilities of social media platforms is therefore an important area of research for disciplines such as political science, international studies, media and communication etc.

\blindtext

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

where `wrapfig` file contain:

```
\begin{wraptable}[18]{r}{45mm}
    \sisetup{table-format=4.0,
             group-minimum-digits=4,
             group-separator={,}
             }
    \SetTblrStyle{caption-tag}{font=\footnotesize\bfseries}
    \SetTblrStyle{caption-text}{font=\footnotesize}
\small
    \begin{talltblr}[
caption={Most popular platforms},
  label={SoMe platforms},
remark{Note}    = {Counted in millions},
remark{Source}  = {\citeauthor{StatA}, \citeyear{StatB}}
                    ]{colspec={ X[l,m] Q[c,m, si] },
                      rowsep = {0pt},
                      row{1} = {font=\bfseries, rowsep=2pt},
                      measure=vbox
                     }
    \toprule
Platform    & {{{Active  
                 users}}}   \\ 
    \midrule
Facebook    & 2 853         \\
YouTube     & 2 291         \\
WhatsApp    & 1 386         \\
Instagram   & 1 386         \\
WeChat      & 1 242         \\
TikTok      &   732         \\
Telegram    &   550         \\
Sina Weibo  &   530         \\
Snapchat    &   514         \\
Pinterest   &   478         \\
Reddit      &   430         \\
Twitter     &   397         \\ 
    \bottomrule
    \end{talltblr}
\end{wraptable}
```

Compilation gives no errors, nine Warnings concerning `biblatex` package and referencing of bibliography items (since bibliography is unknown), no any `Bad Boxes` (concerning `underfull hbox`).

In test I use recent version of MiKTeX.

**Addendum:**

As mentioned @John Kormylo in his comment below, above solution woks by accidentally because the text in line before inserting point end at right text border. If not, this text line is stretched to the border. Result is very ugly (and seems that this is main OP problem).

- This can be solved by move inserting point between two words where there is a natural line break.. See  @Donald Arseneau answer on [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/562095/overfull-hbox-from-wrapfigure/562099#562099).
- Another possibility is use `insbox` macro defined in TeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, 
            hmargin={2.5cm, 3cm}, 
            vmargin={3cm, 3cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document

\usepackage{microtype}
\input{insbox}%%%%%%%%%%%%%% TeX macro, instead of wrapfig

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx, varwidth}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, 
            font=small, 
            labelfont=bf, labelsep=newline]{caption}
\usepackage[style=apa, 
            citestyle=apa, 
            sorting=nyt ]{biblatex}

\begin{document}

\InsertBoxR{3}{\input{wraptable.txt}}[9]
Even though Russia still utilizes 'old media channels' (e.g. television, radio and newspapers) to reach both its domestic audience and audiences outside of its national borders, the reach is limited to Russian speaking minorities abroad. Thus, the Russian state relies heavily on social media to reach non-Russian speaking audiences in the West (\citeauthor{ramsay2019weapon}, \citeyear{ramsay2019weapon}). Examining how Russia utilises the possibilities of social media platforms is therefore an important area of research for disciplines such as political science, international studies, media and communication etc.

\blindtext[1]

\blindtext[1]
\end{document}
```

where `wraptable.txt` is changed to:

```
\begin{minipage}{46mm}
\vspace*{0.5\baselineskip}\hfill
    \sisetup{table-format=4.0,
             group-minimum-digits=4,
             group-separator={,}
             }
    \SetTblrStyle{caption-tag}{font=\footnotesize\bfseries}
    \SetTblrStyle{caption-text}{font=\footnotesize}
\small
    \begin{talltblr}[
caption={Most popular platforms},
  label={SoMe platforms},
remark{Note}    = {Counted in millions},
remark{Source}  = {\citeauthor{StatA}, \citeyear{StatB}}
                    ]{width=44mm,
                      colspec={ X[l,m] Q[c,m, si] },
                      rowsep = {0pt},
                      row{1} = {font=\bfseries, rowsep=2pt},
                      measure=vbox
                     }
    \toprule
Platform    & {{{Active
                 users}}}   \\
    \midrule
Facebook    & 2 853         \\
YouTube     & 2 291         \\
WhatsApp    & 1 386         \\
Instagram   & 1 386         \\
WeChat      & 1 242         \\
TikTok      &   732         \\
Telegram    &   550         \\
Sina Weibo  &   530         \\
Snapchat    &   514         \\
Pinterest   &   478         \\
Reddit      &   430         \\
Twitter     &   397         \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{talltblr}
\end{minipage}
```

[image]

points

Comment: I get the impression that you mostly just got lucky in the word spacing so that the wraptable wound up at the end of a line.  A safer option would be to add a blank line or \par before starting wraprable.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, you are right. `wraptable` or `wrapfigure` is not possible to insert in middle of paragraph (I forgot to emphasize  this fact) . Solution is split this paragraph on two and eventually manually add few first word from the second paragraph. Yes, I was lucky ...

Comment: @JohnKormylo, see addendum to answer.